# How to Rollback DB2 Ingest statement for malformed data

Tags: sql, bash, db2, db2-luw

I have a Bash Shell Script that runs a DB2 sql file. The job of this sql file is to completely replace the contents of a database table with whatever are the contents of this sql file.

However, I also need that database table to have its contents preserved if errors are discovered in the ingested file. For example, supposing my table currently looks like this:

| MY_TABLE | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row0 | 15 | 27 |
| row1 | 19 | 20 |

And supposing I have an input file that looks like this:

```
15,28
34,90
"a string that's obviously not supposed to be here"
54,23
```

If I run the script with this input file, the table should stay exactly the same as it was before, not using the contents of the file at all.

However, when I run my script, this isn't the behavior I observe: instead, the contents of MY_TABLE do get replaced with all of the valid rows of the input file so the new contents of the table become:

| MY_TABLE | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row0 | 15 | 28 |
| row1 | 34 | 90 |
| row2 | 54 | 23 |

In my script logic, I explicitly disable autocommit for the part of the script that ingests the file, and I only call commit after I've checked that the sql execution returned no errors; if it did cause errors, I call rollback instead. Nonetheless, the contents of the table get replaced when errors occur, as though the rollback command wasn't called at all, and a commit was called instead.

Where is the problem in my script?

#### script.ksh

```
SQL_FILE=/app/scripts/script.db2
LOG=/app/logs/script.log

# ...
# Boilerplate to setup the connection to the database server
# ...

# +c: autocommit off
# -v: echo commands
# -s: Stop if errors occur
# -p: Show prompt for interactivity (for debugging)
# -td@: use '@' as the statement delimiter in the file
db2 +c -s -v -td@ -p < $SQL_FILE >> $LOG

if [ $? -gt 2 ];
then echo "An Error occurred; rolling back the data" >> $LOG
db2 "ROLLBACK" >> $LOG
exit 1
fi

# No errors, commit the changes
db2 "COMMIT" >> $LOG
```

#### script.db2

```
ingest from file '/app/temp/values.csv'
format delimited by ','
(
  $C1    INTEGER EXTERNAL,
  $C2    INTEGER EXTERNAL
)
restart new 'SCRIPT_JOB'
replace into DATA.MY_TABLE
(
  C1,
  C2
)
values
(
  $C1,
  $C2
)@
```

Comment: Per the db2 documentation for the `ingest` command: `Updates from the INGEST command are committed at the end of an ingest operation. The INGEST command issues commits based on the commit_period and commit_count configuration parameters. As a result of this, the following do not affect the INGEST command:
the CLP -c or +c options, which normally affect whether the CLP automatically commits
the NOT LOGGED INITIALLY option on the CREATE TABLE statement`   It appears that the `+c: autocommit off` will not function.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest

Comment: @j_b *<user's comment has been redacted due to excessive, graphic uses of profanity. Like, so much of it. Seriously, it went way past the character limit, we have no idea how that even happened>*

Comment: @j_b In all seriousness, this is probably worth posting as an answer, though if someone could offer a workaround, that would be awesome.

Comment: One possible workaround might be to create a new table `my_table_new` that is a copy original DDL for `my_table`.  You could ingest into this new table and once you are happy with the new table, rename `my_table` to `my_table_old` and rename `my_table_new` to `my_table`

Answer (score 1):

Adding as answer per OP's suggestion:

Per the db2 documentation for the [ingest command](https://ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest) It appears that the `+c: autocommit off` will not function:

```
Updates from the INGEST command are committed at the end of an ingest
operation. The INGEST command issues commits based on the commit_period 
and commit_count configuration parameters. As a result of this, the
following do not affect the INGEST command: the CLP -c or +c options, which
normally affect whether the CLP automatically commits the NOT LOGGED
INITIALLY option on the CREATE TABLE statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the [`warningcount 1` option](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest), which will cause the command to terminate after the first error or warning. The default behaviour is to continue processing while ignoring all errors (`warningcount 0`).

Comment: I did try this during debugging before I posted the question; it doesn't solve the rollback issue though, since the table gets wiped (and that wipe committed) before the ingest command stops running. So instead of the table getting replaced with the new data unrecoverably, the table is completely wiped out unrecoverably.